# Android not finding View IDs

Tags: android, xml

So I have a layout that I'm working on, and just to make sure everything is looking OK on an actual phone I'm doing a test run before I move on with the other labels. But, the problem is, Eclipse can only find one id `contactName`. The other id's all have an error saying that Android can't find them. My XML File is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactPicture"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/contactPicture"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactPicture"
            android:text="@string/name" 
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameLabel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameLabel"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/companyName"
            android:text="@string/company" 
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contactPicture"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contactName"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneLabel"
            android:text="Phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contactPicture" 
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contactPicture"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/workNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Work Num"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phoneLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phoneLabel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home Num"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/workNum"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workNum" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobileNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mobile Num"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/homeNum"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/homeNum" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/workLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Work"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/workNum"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/workNum"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/workLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workLabel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobileLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mobile"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/homeLabel"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workLabel" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project.

Comment: 1.duplicate id with other page.
2.something it cannot detect because of R.java
3.Try in emulator and other phone

Comment: Well it can find one of the IDs so I don't think that it is because it can't detect R.java. And I can't run it in the emulator or phone with errors, eclipse tells me to fix the errors first. And I know it's not a duplicate ID, as I don't have many ID's on other pages, this is the only real page with a large number of Views in it.

Comment: check if some IMPORT like...R.android... has been automatically added to your project. This sometimes happens when copy/pasting from other files

Comment: Well I tried cleaning the project and now R.java is missing completely, I'm working to regenerate it now.

Comment: So how to avoid when clean the project,at that time R.java do not miss?

Comment: I'm trying to regenerate R.java, if that doesn't work I may need to. Will copying and pasting over my .xml files work to regenerate the R.java file with the correct id's in it?

Comment: sure because in the R.java there has some memory address of UI so memory address can not same each project. so please remember do not clean the android project. :D

Comment: The new project isn't even creating a new activity and has so many errors in its xml file it's unbelievable...

Comment: When you clean the project, something Eclipse and other DEV tools add, `import com.yourproject.R` in your Java file. You have to delete it from every instance otherwise it won't work correctly.

Comment: Make sure there isn't any (for as tiny as it can be) error in ANY file ending in **xml**. Also make sure you didn't use **upper case** letters while naming your resources.